# Unix shell: how to get the first 3 letters of the filename

Tags: filenames

I want to know in how to get the first 3 letters in a filename in very simple way. Thanks and regards

Comment: Do you have a question? Did you try something? What was wrong with what you tried? Did you do any research yet?

Comment: Yes given that the filename always have letter P in 3rd position, so I here is my code (echo TTPTEST | awk -F"P" '{print $1"P"}') but I wonder if there is more easier way out there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the shell you're using. In `bash`, you can just use the substring extraction, something like:

```
pax> fname=xyzzy.txt

pax> echo ${fname}
xyzzy.txt

pax> first3=${fname:0:3} ; echo ${first3}
xyz
```

If you're not using `bash`, another option is to use `cut`, which tends to be available on most systems. It's an external program, meaning it's not as efficient as the internal `bash` method above, but you'll probably only notice that if you're doing it thousands of times per second.

```
pax> first3=$(echo ${fname} | cut -c1-3) ; echo ${first3}
xyz
```

Comment: Thanks paxdiablo your awesome :)

Comment: My awesome what? Sorry, I'm not usually a pedant to people who compliment me, but the correct phrase is "you're awesome" :-) And why is _some_ awe good (awesome) while lots of awe is bad (awful). I've never been able to figure that one out.